# Post crawl stats collection

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I would like to collect and parse stats after my scrapy crawl has finished. I know it dumps the stats but I would like to ideally have a method/hook a method that runs when the scrape has finished which can then collect the stats (as I will use them to decide if another scrape is needed automatically).

Please don't suggest using some sort of external script, I want it all contained to one project please.

Answer (score 1):

Try to collect stats in `close_spider` method in your custom `pipeline` which runs after crawling process has finished.

```py
class SecuritiesPipeline(object):

    def close_spider(self, spider):
        print(spider.crawler.stats.get_stats())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this command to save progress of spider:
`nohup scrapy crawl spider > spider_progress &`
See only tail of the text file which contains stats of spider: 
`cat spider_progress | tail`